# Truncated Maximum Likelihood estimator

Tags: r, statistics, poisson, mle, probability-distribution

I am trying to estimate the parameters of **Truncated New Generalized Poisson Lindly distribution**.

Here in this distribution, we use two parameters which are `alpha1`, `beta1`, When I run Optimum function then I should get the values of estimators `alpha1`, `beta1`.

I get those values in R, the value of `alpha1` I get is correct,
But the problem is that I am getting the incorrect value of `beta1`.

I have tried to run this in `R`, but the estimate of `beta1` is incorrect.

```
## Data Generation
## PMF of New Generalized Poisson Lindley distribution

marginal=function(alpha1, beta1,x1){
  ab=(alpha1^2*(1+alpha1+beta1+beta1*x1))/((alpha1+beta1)*(alpha1+1)^(x1+2))
  return(ab)
}

alpha1=0.2;beta1=3;Tr=3

t1=c();
for(i in 1:10000){
  a=0:1000
  pr1=marginal(alpha1,beta1,a)
  y1=sample(a,1,replace=TRUE,prob=pr1);
  t1[i]=y1;
}
t1
##_________________###_____________________##___________
length(t1)
summary(t1)
hist(t1)
# Mean and Variance of Untruncated NGPLD

#Mean of Untruncated NGPLD 
U1=function(alpha1,beta1){
  U1=(alpha1+2*beta1)/(alpha1*(beta1+alpha1))
  return(sum(U1))
}
U1(alpha1,beta1);mean(t1)

# Variance of Untruncated NGPLD
var1=function(alpha1,beta1){
  var1=(2*beta1^2*(1+alpha1)+alpha1^2*(1+alpha1)+alpha1*beta1*(4+3*alpha1))/(alpha1^2*(alpha1+beta1)^2)
  return(sum(var1))
}
var1(alpha1,beta1);var(t1)

#Truncated data
Tx=t1[t1>Tr];Tx
hist(Tx)
length(Tx)
#Truncated NEw genralized poisson lindley Disrtribution ,where
#Truncated NGPLD=(PMF/1-Cf),where (1-Cf) is a Survival function

#survival Function
x=Tr
cf=((alpha1+beta1)*(1+alpha1)^(x+2)-(alpha1+alpha1^2+2*alpha1*beta1+alpha1*beta1*x+beta1))/((alpha1+beta1)*(1+alpha1)^(x+2))
1-cf

#Truncated NEw genralized poisson lindley Disrtribution 
UT <-function(x1,alpha1,beta1,Tr){
  x=Tr
  cf=((alpha1+beta1)*(1+alpha1)^(x+2)-(alpha1+alpha1^2+2*alpha1*beta1+alpha1*beta1*x+beta1))/((alpha1+beta1)*(1+alpha1)^(x+2))
  numerator =alpha1^2 * (1 + alpha1 + beta1 + beta1 * x1)
  denominator = (alpha1 + beta1) * (alpha1 + 1)^(x1 + 2)
  result=numerator/denominator
  result1=result/(1-cf)
  return(result1)
}
UT(4:100,0.2,3,3)
#sum of probilities of Truncated NGPLD is one
sum(UT(4:100,0.2,3,3))
plot(Tx,UT(Tx,alpha1,beta1,Tr))

#Mean and Varince of Truncated NGPLD

#mean of Truncated NGPLD
f1=function(alpha1,beta1,Tr){
  x1=Tr+1:100
  f1=(x1*alpha1^2*(1+alpha1+beta1+beta1*x1))/((alpha1+beta1)*(alpha1+1)^(x1+2))
  return(sum(f1))
}
X=f1(alpha1,beta1,Tr)/(1-cf)
X;mean(Tx)

#varince of Truncated NGPLD 

f3=function(alpha1,beta1,Tr){
  x1=Tr+1:100
  f3=(x1*(x1-1)*alpha1^2*(1+alpha1+beta1+beta1*x1))/((alpha1+beta1)*(alpha1+1)^(x1+2))
  return(sum(f3))
}

vx=f3(alpha1,beta1,Tr)/(1-cf)+f1(alpha1,beta1,Tr)/(1-cf)-(f1(alpha1,beta1,Tr)/(1-cf))^2
vx;var(Tx)



#likelihood function of Truncated NGPLD
lik=function(par,data){
  x1<-data
  alpha1=par[1];beta1=par[2];
  ll=-sum(log(UT(Tx, alpha1, beta1,Tr)))
  return(ll)}

# MLE Of Truncated NGPLD
pp=optim(par=c(alph1=1,beta1=2),fn=lik,data=Tx,
         control = list(parscale=c(alph1=1,beta1=1)))
#estimated parameter 
ap1=pp$par[1];bt1=pp$par[2];ap1;bt1
```

Answer (score 2):

Just changed your `negative log-likelihood` function to use `x1` instead of `Tx` and it worked for me

```
nllik <- function(par, data, Tr) { # optionally pass additional constant param which is not an optimization variable
  x1 <- data
  alpha1 <- par[1]
  beta1 <- par[2]
  ll <- -sum(log(UT(x1, alpha1, beta1, Tr)))  # change Tx to x1
  return(ll)
}

# set.seed(1) before data generation to reproduce
pp <- optim(par = c(alph1=1, beta1=2), fn = nllik, data = Tx, Tr = Tr,
                   control = list(parscale = c(alph1=1, beta1=1)))
#estimated parameters
ap1 = pp$par[1]; bt1 = pp$par[2]
ap1; bt1
# alph1 
# 0.20076 
# beta1 
# 2.845234
```

The next plot shows the `negative log-likelihood` function surface as a function of `alpha` and `beta`, the function `optim()` tries to minimize the function, starting from the initial point.

```
library(plot3D)
m <- 500
n <- 25
x <- seq(0.1, 0.3, length=m) 
#x <- c(seq(-1, -0.01, length=25), seq(0.01, 1, length=25))
y <- seq(2, 4, length=n)
z <- matrix(rep(0, m*n), nrow=m)
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  for (j in 1:length(y)) {
    z[i,j] <- llik(c(x[i], y[j]), Tx, Tr)
  }
}
persp3D(x, y, z, #col=colvec, #col=jet.col(256), theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5,
        ticktype='detailed', shade=0.05, contour=TRUE, lighting=TRUE, #curtain=TRUE,
        xlab="alpha", ylab="beta",zlab="nll", main='NLL')
```

[image]

Here is the distribution with MLE fitted parameters, the density plotted on data histogram:

```
Tx = sort(Tx)
hist(Tx, probability = TRUE, main = 'data & MLE fit', col = 'gray')
lines(Tx,UT(Tx,ap1,bt1,Tr), col='red')
legend("topright", legend=c("data", "MLE"), lty = c(NA, 1), border = c("gray", NA), fill = c("gray",NA), col = c(NA, 'red'), x.intersp=c(-1.5,0.5))
```

[image]

#### EDIT

Take a closer look at the contour of the `NLL` function, which we are aiming to minimize:

```
filled.contour(x, y, z, xlab="alpha", ylab="beta",zlab="nll", main='NLL contour')
```

[image]

Note that the `nllik` function is very highly sensitive with the change in value of `alpha`, but less sensitive with the change in the value of `beta` beyond a point.

```
beta <- seq(0.1, 10,length.out=100)
alpha <- c(0.19, 0.2, 0.21)

df <- NULL
for (a in alpha) {
  for (b in beta) {
    df <- rbind(df, data.frame(alpha=a, beta=b, nll=llik(c(a,b), Tx, Tr=3)))
  }
}
head(df)
library(ggplot2)
df$alpha <- as.factor(round(df$alpha,3))
ggplot(df, aes(beta, nll, group=alpha, color=alpha)) + geom_line(lwd=1.25) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c('red', 'green', 'blue')) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Note that the function keeps on decreasing (though the rate of decrease is small) till `beta=10` when `alpha=0.205`, that's why `optim()` finds high `beta` values for this particular value of `alpha` (is it as per expectation? if not, you may want to double-check the function `UT()` for the computation of the pmf for the `TNGPL` distribution from the inverse CDF)

[This](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7907/a32cf3191ca527895781a4e350f24dee396a.pdf) is a good resource to learn more about

> A New Generalized Poisson-Lindley Distribution

It's good to include a reference for a distribution which is not common.

Comment: Thank you @Sandipan
But the problem appears when I run the code multiple times.

What I am trying to say is: The more times I run the code, the more difference in the estimation of `beta1` occurs.


For example:
If I run the code once, the `alpha1` will be `= 0.204324` and `beta1` will be `= 2.53334`
But if I run it 2,3,4 or 5 times, then in one of the runs (Say, the 4th) the value of `beta1` varies with a huge difference as compared to the value of `beta1` in the other runs.

Comment: Here I run the code 10 times using `for` loop, you can notice the values of `beta1` with unusual variance.

Run 1 : alpha1 = 0.1965365 , beta1 = 1.493097
Run 2 : alpha1 = 0.2006077 , beta1 = **5.686871**
Run 3 : alpha1 = 0.203469 , *beta1 = **295.01**
Run 4 : alpha1 = 0.2006209 , beta1 = 3.162834
Run 5 : alpha1 = 0.197675 , beta1 = 2.896276
Run 6 : alpha1 = 0.2006643 , beta1 = 2.160326
Run 7 : alpha1 = 0.1941118 , beta1 = 1.201454
Run 8 : alpha1 = 0.2043193 , beta1 = 2.859404
Run 9 : alpha1 = 0.1992823 , beta1 = 2.859672
Run 10 : alpha1 = 0.1941022 , beta1 = 1.149447

Comment: This large variance in the values of **`beta1`** seems completely random, I don't know how to approach this problem. please help me with this.

Comment: @SanaullahKhan as can be seen from the `neg-log-likelihood` surface as a function of `alpha`, `beta`, the function does not change significantly with `beta`, when compared to the change w.r.t. `alpha`.  Still  I think it is unlikely to converge to the local minimum with a high `beta` value, starting from an initial low value, have you considered changing other hyperparamyers such as increasing number of iterations for convergence, changing the optimization algorithm etc.?

Comment: Note that nllik(c(0.203469, 295.01), Tx, 3) = 24412.32 and nllik(c(0.1965365,  1.493097), Tx, Tr=3) = 24412.66, indicating that with high change in beta the neg-log-lokielihood does not change much, i.e., ∂ (NLL) / ∂β ≈ 0 almost everywhere, for some values of `alpha`  beyond a certain value of `beta`.

Comment: Thank you so much. @Sandipan Dey Could you please provide me with the codes for those graphs?
Especially for the line graph and heat map.

Comment: @Sanaullah Khan Added the code for the visualization